# JSON struct to csv in Go Lang

Tags: json, csv, go, struct

Looking for ideas to export JSON read structs into some csv format while preserving the hierarchy.

https://play.golang.org/p/jf2DRL1hC5K

```
/* 
Expected output in excel for data wrangling: 
A Key       | B Key     | C Key     | D Key
SomethingA    SomethingB      SomethingC      SomethingF 
SomethingA    SomethingB      SomethingC      SomethingG
SomethingA    SomethingB      SomethingC      [1,2,3]   
*/
```

I have tried iterating through the struct as following

```
for _, value := range mymodel { 
   fmt.Println(value) 

/* could not iterate over structs */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a method to your RootModel for both header and individual rows (so you can range over the type and only print the header once):

```
type RootModel struct {
        A string
        B string
        C string
        D factors
}

type factors struct {
        F string
        G string
        H []int
}

func (*RootModel) CSVheader(w io.Writer) {
        cw := csv.NewWriter(w)
        cw.Write([]string{"A Key", "B Key", "C Key", "D Key"})
        cw.Flush()
}

func (rm *RootModel) CSVrow(w io.Writer) {
        cw := csv.NewWriter(w)
        cw.Write([]string{rm.A, rm.B, rm.C, rm.D.F})
        cw.Write([]string{rm.A, rm.B, rm.C, rm.D.G})

        is, _ := json.Marshal(rm.D.H)
        cw.Write([]string{rm.A, rm.B, rm.C, string(is)})
        cw.Flush()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/c8UQVQ8tQTX

Output:

```
A Key,B Key,C Key,D Key
SomethingA,SomethingB,SomethingC,SomethingF
SomethingA,SomethingB,SomethingC,SomethingG
SomethingA,SomethingB,SomethingC,"[1,2,3]"
```

**Note:** if you are dealing with a slice of `RootModel`, you may want to put the CSV writer logic at that level - so it can handle the single render of the header-row and then the subsequent data rows.

Comment: This looks good if I had that format, but my format is actually in a struct. I have read the csv package and I understand that this could be an output in the event I have the data in the expected format - as shown in the above "expected output"  

But my data is all in the struct format. {SomethingA SomethingB SomethingC {SomethingF SomethingG [1 2 3]}}, how would I format this into

Comment: @superenme updated answer to include struct methods to achieve the desired result for a single or multiple record output

Comment: I found another way, since I have many of the root models, alternatively I could iterate over the [] array of root models. I can iterate over arrays just not structs. Thanks a lot of the answer, it definitely helps as well!